# FB send button does not show on page

Tags: facebook

```
<div id="Zoom" style="background-color: blue; top: 1077px; left: 378px;
     position: absolute; display: block;">
    Send 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:send colorscheme="dark" font="" href="http://tinyurl.com/3e7ggl6">
    </fb:send>
    <br> 
    <textarea rows="7" cols="40">bla bla</textarea>
</div>
```

why isn't the Facebook send button visible? Or is it visible only if the page runs inside a Facebook canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to run inside the Facebook Canvas.

You need to have the FB JS SDK on your page. I'm assuming you don't. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

or, just copy this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="Zoom" style="background-color: blue; top: 1077px; left: 378px; position: absolute; display: block;">
    Send 
    <fb:send colorscheme="dark" font="" href="http://tinyurl.com/3e7ggl6">
    </fb:send>
    <br> 
    <textarea rows="7" cols="40">bla bla</textarea>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    status : false, // don't check login status if you don't need it
    cookie : don't, // don't enable cookies to allow the server to access the session unless you need it
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file, see the JS docs
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0 // It's the future, man
  });
</script>
```

That should do it

Comment: I am using Facebook-C#-SDK. I am authenticated. Can you please tell me what code I need to add to this page?

Comment: I've never used the C# SDK (or C# at all for that matter) so this might not be 100% correct, but it looks like you're just echoing out the HTML for the JavaScript SDK to parse and use. I'll add what to do to the answer